# I want to show if $\int |f|d\mu < \infty$ then almost everywhere $|f|< \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory

show that if $\int |f|d\mu < \infty$ then almost everywhere $|f|< \infty$.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointwise inequality $|f|\geqslant+\infty\cdot\mathbf 1_A$ with $A=[|f|=+\infty]$ implies that
$\displaystyle\int|f|\mathrm d\mu\geqslant+\infty\cdot\mu\left(A\right)$. The RHS is finite only if $\mu\left(A\right)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:** Let $E_n = \{x \in X \mid |f(x)| > n\}$ where $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$.

- Show that $E_n$ is measurable.
- Show that $\mu(E_n) < \frac{1}{n}\int_X|f|d\mu$.
- Consider the relationship between $\{x \in X \mid |f(x)| = \infty\}$ and the collection of sets $\{E_n\}$.